# variable has incomplete type 'struct login l;' in C

Tags: c, variables, types

I have a school project to create a program in C, in which users can login through their credentials and vote on a single issue using yes or no.

I got this code for the login system, but is giving an error about incomplete variable type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){

struct login                           // before the first use of `l`.
{
char fname[30];
char lname[30];
char username[30];
char password[20];
};

void login (void);
void registration (void);


int option;

printf("Press '1' to Register\nPress '2' to Login\n\n");
scanf("%d",&option);

getchar();           // catching newline.

if(option == 1)
    {
        system("CLS");
        registration();
    }

else if(option == 2)
    {
        system("CLS");
        login();
    }
    }

    void login (void)
    {
    char username[30],password[20];
    FILE *log;

    log = fopen("login.txt","r");
    if (log == NULL)
    {
    fputs("Error at opening File!", stderr);
    exit(1);
    }

    struct login l;

    printf("\nPlease Enter your login credentials below\n\n");
    printf("Username:  ");
    fgets(username, 30, stdin);
    printf("\nPassword: ");
    printf("\n");
    fgets(password, 20, stdin);

    while(fread(&l,sizeof(l),1,log))
    {
    if(strcmp(username,l.username)==0 && strcmp(password,l.password)==0)

        {   
            printf("\nSuccessful Login\n");
        }
    else 
        {
            printf("\nIncorrect Login Details\nPlease enter the correct credentials\n");
        }
    }

fclose(log);

return;
}




void registration(void)
{ 
char firstname[15];
FILE *log;

log=fopen("login.txt","w");
if (log == NULL)
{
    fputs("Error at opening File!", stderr);
    exit(1);
}


struct login l;

printf("\nWelcome to your online course provider. We need to enter some details for registration.\n\n");
printf("\nEnter First Name:\n");
scanf("%c",l.fname);
printf("\nEnter Surname:\n");
scanf("%s",l.lname);

printf("Thank you.\nNow please choose a username and password as credentials for system login.\nEnsure the username is no more than 30 characters long.\nEnsure your password is at least 8 characters long and contains lowercase, uppercase, numerical and special character values.\n"); 
}
```

This is the error I'm getting at line 50 and 93

```
Main.c:50:18: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct login'
struct login l;
             ^
Main.c:50:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct login'
struct login l;
       ^
Main.c:93:18: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct login'
struct login l;
             ^
`Main.c:93:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct login'
struct login l;
```

Can someone please help me with the error?

Comment: Move `struct login` definition *out* of `main`, ideally above it. Immediately after the `#include` stack looks to be a nice place of it.

Comment: @WhozCraig really sorry to bother you, but can you please do it for me? I tried it, but it starts giving me 19 errors. I'm still a beginner, so your help would be appreciated

Comment: Your code would be easier to read (both for yourself and for other people) if you used consistent [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).

Comment: move the functin decalarations out too - they work inside main but its very unusual to see them like that

Answer (score 1):

Move the strruct definition like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct login                           
{
   char fname[30];
   char lname[30];
   char username[30];
   char password[20];
};
int main(void){
```

to be outside and before all functions

Move the function declarations too

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct login                           
{
   char fname[30];
   char lname[30];
   char username[30];
   char password[20];
};

void login (void);
void registration (void);

int main(void){
```